# Ramanujan's tau function, $691$ congruence, and $\eta(z)^{12}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, congruences

Let $q = e^{2\pi i\,z}$.

> **I. 24th power**

The Ramanujan tau function $\tau(n)$ is given by the expansion of the Dedekind eta function $\eta(z)$'s $\text{24th}$ power. Then

$$\begin{aligned}\eta(z)^{24} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau(n)q^n\\&=q - 24q^2 + 252q^3 - 1472q^4 + 4830q^5 - 6048q^6 - 16744q^7 + \dots\end{aligned}$$

Ramanujan observed that

$$\tau(n)\equiv\sigma_{11}(n)\ \bmod\ 691\tag1$$

> **II. 12th power**

Assume the rho function $\rho(n)$ as,

$$\begin{aligned}\eta(2z)^{12} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho(n)q^n\\&=q - 12q^3 + 54q^5 - 88q^7 -99q^9 +540q^{11} - 418q^{13} -648q^{15} + \dots\end{aligned}$$

Note the odd powers. Is it true that

$$\rho(n)\equiv\sigma_{5}(n)\ \bmod\ 2^8\tag2$$

analogous to $(1)$?

**P.S.** It's true for the first 10000 coefficients in OEIS [A000735](https://oeis.org/A000735).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, this is true, as a consequence of an identity in a space of
modular forms of weight $6$.

The form $\eta(2z)^{12}$ is in this space; and $\sigma_5(n)$ for $n$ odd
are the coefficients of the weight-$6$ form
$$
\frac1{1008} \Bigl(E_6(z+\frac12) - E_6(z)\Bigr) =
q + 244 q^3 + 3126 q^5 + 16808 q^7 + 59293 q^9 + \cdots.
$$
The difference is
$$
256(q^3 + 12 q^5 + 66 q^7 + 232 q^9 + 627 q^{11} + 1452 q^{13} + \cdots);
$$
after a bit of experimentation we recognize this as $256q^3$ times the
$12$-th power of $1+q^2+q^6+q^{12}+q^{20}+\cdots$, which is to say
$256$ times the $12$-th power of the weight-$1/2$ modular form
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^{(2k+1)^2/4}$.  Such a formula, once surmised,
can be proved by comparing initial segments of the $q$-expansions;
I did this to $O(q^{61})$, which is way more than enough.
The congruence mod $256$ follows because the $12$-th power of
$1+q^2+q^6+q^{12}+q^{20}+\cdots$ clearly has integral coefficients.

*Added later*:
This identity (and thus the congruence that **Tito Piezas III** asked for)
gives a formula $(\sigma_5(n) - \rho(n)) / 256$ for the number of
representations of $4n$ as the sum of $12$ odd squares, or equivalently of
$(n-3)/2$ as the sum of $12$ triangular numbers.  Following this lead,
I soon found both the formula and the congruence in the paper

> Ken Ono, Sinai Robins, and Patrick T. Wahl: On the representation of integers as sums of triangular numbers, *Aequationes Math.* **50** (1995) #1, 73-94

available
[on
  Ken Ono's page](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/006.pdf),
where the enumeration is given (in the triangular-number form) as Theorem 7,
and the congruence as a "simple consequence" of that theorem.

Comment: Is there a conceptual explanation of why this is true?

Comment: As with the Ramanujan identity in weight $12$, the space is of low enough dimension that if you've constructed enough forms there must be a linear relation.  Why it's this particular relation I don't know.  (The $691$ famously arises as the numerator of a Bernoulli number.)

Comment: Perhaps one should notice that the Bernoulli number Noam refers to is $B_{12}$.

Comment: $E_6(z + 1) - E_6(z)$ is identically zero. Do you maybe mean $E_6(z + \tfrac{1}{2})$?

Comment: If anything it would have been $E_6(\frac{z+1}{2}) - E_6(\frac{z}{2})$
as the question was originally posed (in terms of $\eta(z)^{12}$).
Now that it's $\eta(2z)^{12}$, yes, I'll have to change this too.

Answer (score 4):

To keep the discussion alive and local, I add here further manifestations of the above behavior. Let $q = e^{2\pi i z}$,

> **III. 8th power**

Define the numbers $a(n)$ according to

$$\begin{aligned}\eta(3z)^8 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)q^n\\
&=q - 8q^4 + 20q^7 - 70q^{13}+64q^{16} +56q^{19} - 125q^{25} -160q^{28} + \dots\end{aligned}$$
Then I claim that
$$a(n)\equiv \sigma_3(n) \mod 81.$$

> **IV. 6th power**

Define the numbers $b(n)$ according to

$$\begin{aligned}\eta(4z)^6 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty b(n)q^n\\
&=q - 6q^5 + 9q^9+10q^{13}-30q^{17} +11q^{25}+42q^{29}-70q^{37} + \dots\end{aligned}$$
Then I claim that
$$b(n)\equiv \sigma_3(n) \mod 4.$$

Comment: I think the "tradition" here is to ask such variations as a new question.  At any rate, the first one of these ("II", for $\eta^8$) has an answer similar to what I gave for **Tito Piezas III**'s question: the difference is $81$ times the fourth power of the theta function of $r+3A_2$ where $r$ is any of the minimal vectors of the $A_2$ lattice.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I edited the phrasing on "tradition". Also, the two claims now have serial number "III" and "IV".

Comment: OK, so I, II, III, IV correspond to $\eta^{24/m}$ with $m=1,2,3,4$.
But the IV you suggest is not of the same kind, because 
you're comparing modular forms of different weights (and the common factor is much smaller).  
Also the $q^n$ coefficient of $\eta^6$ can be computed from the
representation(s) of $n$ as a sum of two squares (as you can surmise
from the vanishing of the $q^{21}$ and $q^{33}$ coefficients),
which should let you prove the congruence mod $4$ directly.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: I've made the argument of the Dedekind eta function for I, II, III, IV consistent with q.

Comment: Any clue about the plausible link between the numerator of $\zeta(12)/\pi^{12}$ and the Ramanujan congruence?

Comment: That's well understood: there's a denominator of $\zeta(12)$ in the normalizing factor of the $q$-series for $E_{12}$.